# How do you show visual countdowns for Destiny 2 abilities?

Tags: destiny-2

I am playing Destiny 2 and my abilities have cool downs, but I wasn’t able to see a setting anywhere really that would enable a countdown with numbers, to indicate how long it will be.

Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, cooldowns are only displayed with a white line slowly filling up the box until it is filled and changed to a colored box correlating to your subclass. There is no way to change it to a numbered countdown like those of MMO's or MOBA's.